# How to secure grails API that uses Azure with Oauth?

Tags: azure, grails, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I am new to grails and Azure. I have a grails API that uploads and downloads documents to Azure blob storage. The API is used by consumers who need to be authenticated using Oauth 2.0. I found a grails plugin https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth2-provider that claims to provide oauth tokens for authentication. Is this the best way to authenticate a grails API service?

Azure also seems to provide Oauth 2.0 authentication to an active directory. Instead of using the grails plugin, how is it possible to leverage Azure's Oauth authentication for an active directory to grant access to the grails API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring the [spring security core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) and [spring security rest](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest) grails plugins to set up a token based authentication is the simplest and straightforward way to implement authentication for a grails API.

Answer (score 1):

We are using [Spring Security Core Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) and [OAuth2 Provider](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth2-provider) to secure `Grails API`. It will secure the API's, by restricting access to authorized users based on their `role`.

You can have in depth look how Spring Security Core Plugin provides the base for the OAuth [here.](https://github.com/Abhinandan81/grails-spring-security)